# regular expression pattern about word boundary in python

Tags: python, regex

I want to replace the beginning two letters "or" in "organization" with "*" useing python's re.sub function. I read some books about regular expression that say `\b` represents word boundary, so I used `\bor` as the pattern. But I got:

```
>>> re.sub("\bor","*","organization")
'organization'
>>>
```

I think I should got *ganization. What's the matter and how should I use re pattern to get what I want? Thank you.

Comment: Don't use pictures. put in in as plain text formatted.

Comment: I highly recommend you try checking your RegExs at http://regexpal.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a [raw-string](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) here:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r"\bor", "*", "organization")
'*ganization'
>>>
```

Otherwise, Python sees `\b`, which gets translated to `\x08`:

```
>>> '\b'
'\x08'
>>>
```

---

Another solution would be to escape the backslash:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub("\\bor", "*", "organization")
'*ganization'
>>>
```

---

Yet another (and probably the best) solution would be to use `^` in place of `\b`:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub("^or", "*", "organization")
'*ganization'
>>>
```

In Regex, using `^` like this means "match at the start of the string".

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way that you could do this using the built-in `replace` function.

```
string = "organization"
print string.replace(string[:2], "*")
```